# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors, Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I get an error when try to start application:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'md-select'.
1. If 'md-select' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-select' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
```

I am not sure that I understand problem. But I have import:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: can you also show us your HTML please?

Comment: Do you have sub-modules? If so, did you import FormsModule there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormsModule is missing in your app.

> Do the following in your app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
// ...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Add FormsModule in your imports[]  
    FormsModule,
    // ...    
  ],
```